# Null pointer exception in Simple Facebook library to getPosts?

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception, android-simple-facebook

I imported [THIS LIBRARY](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) to get my all posts i set up all imports and so, I have follow the steps and wirte this code,Actually i wanted to show my page's all public posts in my app.like some apps or website keeps that is looks like facebook's real page. is it possible or not in android? thanks.

```
package algonation.com.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.actions.Cursor;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.entities.Post;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.listeners.OnPostsListener;

import java.util.List;


public class FacebookActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private final static String EXAMPLE = "";
private String mAllPages = "";
OnPostsListener onPostsListener = new OnPostsListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(List<Post> posts) {
        Log.i(EXAMPLE, "Number of posts = " + posts.size());
    }

/*
 * You can override other methods here:
 * onThinking(), onFail(String reason), onException(Throwable throwable)
 */
};

private TextView mResult;
private Button mGetButton;
private TextView mMore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);
    mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    mMore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.load_more);
    mMore.setPaintFlags(mMore.getPaint().getFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    mGetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mGetButton.setText(EXAMPLE);
    mGetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAllPages = "";
            mResult.setText(mAllPages);
            SimpleFacebook.getInstance().getPosts(new OnPostsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onThinking() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
                    mResult.setText(throwable.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFail(String reason) {
                    mResult.setText(reason);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(List<Post> response) {
                    // make the result more readable.
                    mAllPages += "<u>\u25B7\u25B7\u25B7 (paging) #" + getPageNum() + " \u25C1\u25C1\u25C1</u><br>";
                    mAllPages += com.sromku.simple.fb.utils.Utils.join(response.iterator(), "<br>", new com.sromku.simple.fb.utils.Utils.Process<Post>() {
                        @Override
                        public String process(Post post) {
                            return "\u25CF " + post.getMessage() == null || "null".equalsIgnoreCase(post.getMessage()) ? post.getId() : post.getMessage() + " \u25CF";
                        }
                    });
                    mAllPages += "<br>";
                    mResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(mAllPages));
                    // check if more pages exist
                    if (hasNext()) {
                        enableLoadMore(getCursor());
                    } else {
                        disableLoadMore();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_facebook, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void enableLoadMore(final Cursor<List<Post>> cursor) {
    mMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mAllPages += "<br>";
            cursor.next();
        }
    });
}

private void disableLoadMore() {
    mMore.setOnClickListener(null);
    mMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the file `FacebookActivity.java` in **full** length, no lines missing. It's important because otherwise it's not possible to figure out the crashing line.

Comment: Looks like `SimpleFacebook.getInstance()` is null (or the ID for `mResult` is incorrect and _that_ is null)

Comment: @RAnders00 ataulm  i want to show my all public status and pictures in my app. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [code of the library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/blob/master/simple-fb/src/main/java/com/sromku/simple/fb/SimpleFacebook.java#L166), you'll see this note:

```
/**
 * Get the instance of {@link com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook}. <br>
 * <br>
 * <b>Important:</b> Use this method only after you initialized this library
 * or by: {@link #initialize(android.app.Activity)} or by {@link #getInstance(android.app.Activity)}
 *
 * @return The {@link com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook} instance
 */
```

You should use `SimpleFacebook.getInstance(FacebookActivity.this)` because the method you're using will return an uninitialised reference (null), unless you have initialised it previously.

Please spend some time [reading the documentation of the library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/wiki/Configuration) - the guy has clearly spent some time working on huge wiki.

Comment: @atalum this is not giving me the posts.. showing "you are not logged in" but the app must shows page's post without signing in.

Comment: Please open a new question/ask the author of the library. I'd suggest reading the documentation for the library, and trying to achieve your goal (loading public posts) with the bare minimum code. If you are unable, then it may be a misunderstanding in how you think the library works or a bug in the library.